# What are regular epimorphisms of coalgebras?

Tags: ct.category-theory, coalgebras

It is known that epimorphisms between coalgebras are surjective maps. My question is

```
What are regular epimorphisms between coalgebras?
```

I am in particular interested in cocommutative coalgebras, in which case a kernel pair of $D \rightarrow C$ is computed by $D\otimes_C D$, and hence the question is when do we have the canonical isomorphism

$$C \cong D\Big{/}\Big{\{}\sum_i\Big{(}\epsilon(x_i)\otimes y_i - x_i\otimes\epsilon(y_i)\Big{)}\Big{|}\sum_i x_i\otimes y_i \in D\otimes_C D\Big{\}}$$